# Pycharm not showing the true plot generated

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm trying to generate a plot with no space between the subplots. I couldn't get it to work until I checked the saved figure and it turns out it *had* been working, but the plot Pycharm brings up is not the same as the plot saved.
This is a matplotlib example (https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/ganged_plots.html) word for word. The image shown in the Pycharm interface and the one saved using plt.savefig are different.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

s1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
s2 = np.exp(-t)
s3 = s1 * s2

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)
# Remove horizontal space between axes
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

# Plot each graph, and manually set the y tick values
axs[0].plot(t, s1)
axs[0].set_yticks(np.arange(-0.8, 1.0, 0.4))
axs[0].set_ylim(-1, 1)

axs[1].plot(t, s2)
axs[1].set_yticks(np.arange(0.1, 1.0, 0.2))
axs[1].set_ylim(0, 1)

axs[2].plot(t, s3)
axs[2].set_yticks(np.arange(-0.9, 1.0, 0.4))
axs[2].set_ylim(-1, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image: enter code here]

[image]

Is this a known bug with Pycharm? My Pycharm version is 2020.2.3 and I'm using python 3.8.

Comment: It's hard for anyone to make any comments without seeing your code.

Comment: I've added the code in; it's word for word the code in the example link. This was just an example to test it wasn't just my own code causing the problem.